# Is it possible to override vendor/magento/module-sales/Api/Data/OrderAddressInterface.php

Tags: magento2, overrides, rest-api, interface

Is it possible to override vendor/magento/module-sales/Api/Data/OrderAddressInterface.php as I want to get sales order address custom column value in order REST API.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to override the interfaces using the `preference`. Magento 2 does not allow Third-party developers to change the API Data interfaces defined in the Magento Core code.

Please try to use the `Extension attributes` to achieve your requirement. Extension attributes extend functionality and often use more complex data types than custom attributes. These attributes do not appear on the GUI.

Please refer to the Magento DevDocs for more information **[here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html)**.

Also, refer to this post with similar question if it helps! 
[Magento 2 : Override core Interface and Model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213753/magento-2-override-core-interface-and-model)

Comment: But I'm not able get sales order address custom column value in order REST API. Could you please help me on this

Comment: Please check this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235947/how-to-expose-a-custom-field-from-sales-order-table-to-rest-api

Comment: I want to get the custom attribute value from sales order address table that to in shipping address. I'm using magento 2.3.2 EE

Comment: Friends please help me

Comment: Have you tried to use an extension attribute and get the value of the custom attribute?  Check the example here: https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-get-value-of-custom-attribute-on-magento-2-rest-api/

Comment: Yes. I tried tis for sales_order table custom attribute and it helped me to get that value. but I'm unable to get the value of shipping address.

Comment: Try this out: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93143/magento2-how-to-get-shipping-address-for-order-in-rest-api

Comment: Hi Bhaumik, Actually we have a partner vendor they just run order REST API with the search criteria order status in processing. While they run the order REST API they get all the values related to orders and shipping adress under extention attributes. onc e they get shipping address id from this they will run the rest api to get customer address as hey are unable to get the door number value as this is a custom column in sales order address table. But they don't want to run the address api. they want door number in the order api itself. could you please suggest me a workaround.